# Dreamweaver on click

Tags: html, dreamweaver

Hey guys below is the code i have in html in Dreamweaver cs 6 for my button just to go from index_home.html(witch is a login) to the index_main.html page there is no logic behind this i just need the onclick/href= to work but for some reason mine doesn't!
using dreamweaver cs 6, html 5.

im not a newcomer to html , just dreamweaver : here is code!

```
    <div id="Buttons">
<br/>
  <form method="post" name="buttons" id="buttons">
    <button name="Login" id="Login" href="index_main.html">LogIn</button>
    <button name="Register" id="Register" >Register</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

just the login that has the href in it so long, dont wanna go on until i got this basic stuff working :)
any ideas will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have a href on a button.

Either:

- Make it into an `a` tag with a href
- Do an onclick to redirect
- Make the button a submit button `type="submit"`, and set the forms `action` to the page
  you want to be sent to.

Comment: thanks allot Andy, the button submit with the form's action worked exactly the way i wanted! :) , if i have 2 buttons in a div does that mean i must make 2 form tags and a button in each form tag? and each form tag with a different action?

Comment: Yes, submit buttons are generally for submitting form data, whereas you seem to just want a hyperlink. I would recommend `<a href="">` with styling to look like a button rather than doing multiple forms if I were you

Comment: yes but a bit later on the actual login logic will be inserted with javascript, so i will need the form to send data to the next form? so i stick with the submit buttons then?

Comment: Yes, if you want to submit data, a form and a submit button is best

Comment: awesome! thanks alto for ya help i get it now! actually basic error from my side!